# Fixed stretching background image

Tags: html, css, xhtml, responsive-design

I have drafted up a brief example of what I have so far, and what I'm trying to achieve.

See my demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kztGj/20/)

In my jsfiddle you will see a wrapping div named "content-wrap". Within this div I want an image that can stretch to window size and content.

I have done background image stretching before: See example [here](http://maycontainnuts.co.nz/)

But this is a bit more complicated because it is for a specific region within the site.

I have tried having a play so far with my existing code from the link above and I think I may need to take a different approach. As when you scroll down the images doesn't stay in position it moves with the scroll bar (as it should).

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean, as a background image. Hows this http://jsfiddle.net/kztGj/22/ ?

Comment: @Jeemusu Yes as a background image - your example is very close just the image cannot have a fixed height as content will fill the page therefore increasing page height.

Comment: If you remove the height, as in iteration 22  jsfiddle.net/kztGj/22 ? Wait, how do you mean fixed height? You have a fixed height of 300px set on the container?

Comment: yes just to get the background color to show. On the content div I will not have a fixed height as the content will fill that div.

Comment: Ok, but my image doesn't have a fixed height, if you expand the height of the container to 1000px (which is greater than the 900px of the image) you will see it stretches to fit the container.

Comment: Added the responsive-design tag as I think this probably falls into responsive-design territory.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using CSS3's `background-size` property, then the following additions to your `#content-wrap {` CSS statements will achieve a responsive background image that will expand to fit the size of the container.

```
#content-wrap {
    height: 1000px;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #fff;

    /* Added CSS */

    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    background: transparent url("http://placekitten.com/900/900") top right no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Here is an updated version of your jsfiddle with my added CSS and some lovely placekittens: 
http://jsfiddle.net/kztGj/22/

The downsides to this are of course that it will not work in Internet Explorer < 9, Firefox 3.6, or any browser that doesn't support CSS3. But then your asking for a responsive image, and as such you'll be hard pushed to find an elegant solution that supports older browsers.

For more information on the `background-size` property and its uses, I recommend checking out [this article](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/03/02/using-css-background-size-responsively/), its quite informative.

Comment: Here is a wonderful JS that can bring this to IE for you - https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.backgroundSize.js

Answer (score 0):

In your image, add a **css** like this

```
.custom-image {
    width:100%;
}
```

and your **html**

```
<div>
    <img src="" class="custom-image" />
</div>
```